# Nifi - Invalid cors request when uploading template, behind proxy

Tags: proxy, apache-nifi

I have set up a secure NiFi instance (with keycloak) in docker behind proxy. Although everything works as expected when I try to upload a template NiFi gives me "invalid cors request" error and in developer tools I get 403 unauthorized. If i try to upload the template through the server:port it works fine. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

I already tried some headers in apache directives but as fas as i can understand the problem is not the cors error but the 403 unauthorized.

I followed these [these](https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/10/03/apache-nifi-openid-connect) steps in order to integrate NiFi with keycloak.

Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might face this issue in the future. The error indicates that the request is not authorized behind proxy - Ngnix cant authorize the request (from NiFi was authorized) .

I was able to fix this by adding these to my apache directives section:

```
ProxyPreserveHost       On
ProxyRequests           Off
AllowEncodedSlashes     NoDecode
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me solve the same problem, but with nginx, by adding this directive :

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`